# Facebook iOS SDK Pass parameter with app requests

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I would like to have my native iOS app send a request with a parameter to a Facebook user on iOS.  If they accept, it will launch my native iOS app and pass it the parameter.  Is this possible?

I am having marginal success using [facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:dict andDelegate:self].  I am getting the bookmark counter to increment on Facebook iOS app, but I do not see the individual requests.  If I tap the bookmark it launches my app but I do not see how I can get the "data" parameter I passed with the request, or even the request_id.

On desktop I see the individual messages under "Requests" section of "Apps and Games".  If I accept a request, I can see it pass the request_id to my (simple echo) canvas URL.  I read this can be used to fetch the associated data.  But, this does not help me on iOS.  My app only runs on iOS, so this canvas app will eventually just be a "this app only works on iOS," but it seemed to be necessary to get the requests to flow.

Neither of these are showing me Notifications, so maybe I am doing something basic wrong.  Or, is there some other way to pass a message to a Facebook user, with a URL they could click (to launch and feed my app its parameter).

One other odd thing, I do not see how to get rid of the Requests.  If I "X" them on the desktop client, it asks me if I want to stop receiving all requests from my app, and if I say no, it only hides them temporarily.

Comment: not sure, but are you searching for "Deep Linking" ?

Answer (score 1):

Leif, Hi - I'm the engineer at Facebook who wrote the tutorial you've referenced.
I've taken a look at the issue you've mentioned - this is in fact not a bug in the documentation and is by design.

The incoming url from a request on iOS looks something like this:

*`fb480369938658210://authorize?expires_in=3600&access_token=BAAG05NeN86IBAC31YWMWRHVrNCAYMy0Rv1OtqZCwdH8QDBUAt5KgZCsIbU0EOZAvMms2tZCANV9sZBWSkEzStDtt4i7YnYZA4bPgGx2XaI5s22iBMxIZAneZAv7ADi3Wi20ZD&target_url=http%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fapps%2Ffriendsmashsample%3Ffb_source%3Dnotification%26request_ids%3D364209433669109%252C379616028785376%252C494409170593789%252C489782271042929%252C328564930575784%26ref%3Dnotif%26app_request_type%3Duser_to_user`*

This is bundling together several requests, with multiple request ids into a single url.

To get the extra data coupled with this request, it is not required to have the user_id. Hitting graph.facebook.com/*request_id* is enough.

You can actually see this outlined in the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#deleting under the 'Request ID Format' heading.

The code contained in the Friendsmash sample and on the tutorial works correctly - I verified it just now. So it should serve as a good guide to the OP's question.

Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why my app_requests would not trigger Notifications?  They increment my app book mark counter and I can read the app data, and delete the requests.  I just do not ever see the globe highlight on iOS Facebook app, when using my personal account.  I have seen it show the Notification on the desktop www interface but only very rarely.  One of my testers sees the Notifications on iOS, so it must be something with FB account settings or history, but I have tried every conceivable switch I can find on both iOS and www app.  I wonder if it could be some sneaky spam blocking algorithm?

Comment: How are you triggering the app request? From where? Can you please file the report at devsupport@fb.com - Thanks.

Comment: I am using @"apprequests" dialog in iOS SDK, vintage 2010.  The client-side API seems so straightforward, I think the problem must be with the "Facebook app" setup.  I guess I should upgrade to latest SDK and check out current docs and app config before filing report.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this too.

First, the [FB iOS SDK requests tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/requests/) is a good start.

However, there are also a few bugs that makes things not work as expected:

- It seems that currently, a mobile web url has to be set up for the FB app in order for requestIds to be forwarded from the native FB app to your native app. See this [bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/465760136778889).
- The tutorial mentioned above uses an erroneous graph path for the request object. I uses "request-id" where it should be "request-id"_"user-id". I have filed a documentation [bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/457112520997019) on that issue.